# get data from database the user has no access to

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I try to get just 1 item out of a database to which the current user doesn't has access to

I tried :

```
var db:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("","somedir/somedatabase.nsf");
var somedata= (@Unique(@DbLookup(db,"viewname","searchkey",2)));
```

this only seems to work when the user does have access.
What is the best way of dooing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the use of `@DBLookup` because the first parameter of @DBLookup must be a string and not an object of type `NotesDatabase`!

Instead of @DBLookup try this, it should work:

```
var db:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase("","somedir/somedatabase.nsf");
var notesView:NotesView = db.getView(viewname);
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = notesView.getAllDocumentsByKey(searchkey, true);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: When I try your code and then var test= doc.getItemValue("columnname"); I'm getting an error : [TypeError] Error calling method 'getItemValue(string)' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.DocumentCollection [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.DocumentCollection: lotus.domino.DocumentCollection]'

Comment: How would you retrieve a value of a given column ?

Comment: I just found out : var doc:NotesDocument = dc.getFirstDocument();
test= doc.getItemValueString("fieldname"); I guess I have to recycle doc , dc and the notesView ?

Comment: Yes you should recycle your domino objects a soon as possible